# Deleted Network manger trying to install from usb hasn't worked for 2 days

Tags: 16.04, package-management, kubuntu, network-manager, dpkg

The title pretty much explains it. I accidentally deleted network manager and have rebooted my system since. Thus, it is no longer in the cache folder in `/var`. The other issue is I cannot get a wired connection on my computer as I have to use a USB to Ethernet and cannot even install the driver for Linux.

From what I've read I just have to find the `network-manager.deb` and  run `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` to install it. The issue is I can't find the file or package that contains it anywhere.

I have downloaded `network-manager_1.1.10ubuntu0.16.04.3.debian.tar.xz`, and have the original USB with the Ubuntu ISO and the above mentioned file on it. Again my efforts have been fruitless in finding the actual .deb file. Now there is a Debian folder (nothing in it ends in .deb) in the folder I extracted it to, but it seems nothing in there aids the install. and nothing I've found online has helped.

If anyone could give me some steps to remedy this or tell me where I can find `network-manager.deb` it would be greatly appreciated. Also, I'd much prefer not having to boot from the live USB if possible, because I tried a method involving that and it was disastrous to say the least.

Comment: It sounds like you downloaded the source tarball, instead of the pre-built .deb package for your architecture

Comment: So for the tarball would I have to build it myself through themail she'll commands and other files in the folder on my own? Also I got the answer I was looking for and thank you for you response. I'm just curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [this web page](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/xenial/main/updates/network-manager). You can directly download the .deb file for your architecture by clicking the appropriate mustard colored button.

Comment: Thank you so much that was the exact site I was looking for